# How to keep PointWidth fixed and add scrollbar in Range bar Chart

Tags: c#, charts, scrollbar

I have a gantt chart contrains tasks.
I  declared  the PointWidth as 0.25

```
 GanttChart.Series["Tasks"]["PointWidth"] = "0.25";
```

this works good when I have few tasks but whenever I have more tasks the pointWidth (range) becomes smaller and smaller!

I want to keep it 0.25 and to put scrollbar when there are many tasks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [CustomProperty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dd456764%28v%3dvs.140%29) `PointWidth` is in percent of the visible axis.

So with one point the bar or column is really fat and the more data points you add the thinner they will get.

If you want to keep a **fixed width** while changing the number of data points you need to use `PixelPointWidth` instead.

Note however that by default now the bars/columns get **closer and closer** to each other until the **overlap**.

To give them enough room and show scollbars instead, you need to enable the built-in **zooming** mechanism as MSChart will not use normal `Scrollbars`.

This should help:

```
Series s = chart1.Series[0];
s.SetCustomProperty("PixelPointWidth", "12");  // 12 pixels

var ca = chart1.ChartAreas[0];
ca.AxisX.ScrollBar.Enabled = true;
ca.AxisX.ScaleView.Size = 30;         // show a value range of 30

chart1.Refresh();    // usally not needed, but we change a custom property
```

Note that the `ScaleView.Size` is in **data values**. This is the **3rd of the three coordinate system** in the chart: percentages, pixels and values! Very powerful and rather tricky..